# Can we give range at named port declaration and not at time of identifier declaration in verilog

Tags: parsing, syntax, verilog

```
module some ( .a( i [2:0] ), .b( j [0:5] ) )
    input i;
    output j;
endmodule
```

Is above declaration valid or we have to give range at `input [2:0] i;` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must separately declare `i` and `j` with suitable ranges.

When you use the `.name(expression)` syntax in a port list, you are:

- setting the external name of the port to `name`, and
- explaining how to connect it to the declared ports of the module

For instance, consider a module like this:

```
module some (.a(i[2:0]), .b(i[7:3]))
  input [7:0] i;
endmodule
```

Here the module `some` will have two externally visible ports:

- a 3-bit port called `a`, and
- a 5-bit port called `b`,

So a valid instance of this module could look like:

```
some mysome (.a(3'b110), .b(5'b11001));
```

Internally, these bits will get mashed together to create `i == 8'b 11001_110`.

For more information see Section 12.3.1 of the Verilog-2005 standard, or Section 23.2.2.1 of the [SystemVerilog-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) standard (which are both very similar, and both have examples.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusing the syntax, in the example you `.a` which refers to a port called a which does not exist in your code. Just to clarify:

Declaring a module

```
module some (
    input  [2:0] i,
    output [5:0] j
);
endmodule
```

Instancing a module:

```
reg  [2:0] a;
wire [5:0] b;
module_name instance_name (
 .i( a [2:0] ),
 .j( b [5:0] )
);
```

Comment: This is not correct.  The `.name(expr)` syntax explicitly allows for external names (e.g., `a` and `b`) that different from the internal port names (e.g., `i` and `j`).  In general, the `expr` can have arbitrary concatenations of part/bit selects of the (later) declared ports.  (It is definitely uncommon to do this, though!)